# problem installing Maps SDK for Android Utility Setup (android-maps-utils)

Tags: android, google-maps

Hi I'm new to Android and I am doing my first steps. I;m trying to byild and App with google map and I need the Android Utility. But When I try to setup I follow the instructions from google map web site, https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/setup
But I receive the following error
[image]

I change the word compile to implementation and the error disappear is the solution?

[image]

Comment: what is your question ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes configuration "compile" has been deprecated and been replaced with "implementation". Sorry doesn't have enough reputations to add a comment :)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Really appreciate that you tried to help. Try to add bit more explanation. One liners doesn't look too appealing.

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj There wasn't much to explain but sure will keep that in mind